# Prevent CLion from re-formatting code on close brace

Tags: c++, ide, clion

If I have:

```
<code>
<more code>
<some more code>
```

If I want to put `<more code>` in its own scope, I do:

```
<code>
{
    <more code>
| <-- cursor position
<some more code>
```

As soon as I hit `}`, CLion reformats `<more code>` according to its style guidelines.

I don't want it to do this. How do I prevent it from doing this?

Answer (score 2):

According to [Alexey Utkin](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/207379725-Prevent-CLion-from-re-formatting-code-on-close-brace?page=1#community_comment_207631899) on the JetBrains forum:

> You need to switch off the option [ ] Reformat Block on typing '}'
>   The option is in File | Settings...| Editor | General | Smart Keys dialog.
>
> Please, read more here:
>   https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/smart-keys.html